# Upload Youtube video with "fixed" token in Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C for REST

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to create an app that upload video on a specified channel, without prompt a login page. I'll try to explain better what i need.

I'm using Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C for REST, with this library i can use a "standard" upload flow :

user record a video -> he press an upload button -> Safari open the login google page -> user login in his own account and give permission to the app -> Safari redirect back to the ios app -> the upload process begin -> the video will be uploaded on the personal user channel.

Instead this is the desired workflow of my ios app:

user record a video -> he press an upload button -> the video will be uploaded in the app's youtube channel.

The only help i had find is this [article](http://www.whitewareweb.com/php-youtube-video-upload-google-api-oauth-2-0-v3/) ,it explain a way to obtain a refreshable app token to upload video in an app channel. It is exactly what i need. Anyway this is a web example, it uploads videos that are in a server. My videos are in the phone, so i think that i have to modify the flow of this article in this way:

obtain token the first time by login as channel owner -> create a token.txt and save it in my server -> create a page called get_token.php that print the content of token.txt and refresh it if the token expire.

With this flow in my app i need this other flow:

user record a video -> press an upload button -> i made a call to get_token.php and retrive the actual token -> i made a call by library with the token retrived to upload the video on the app's youtube channel.

Here i have found some problems, this is my authentication methods :

```
#pragma mark - Sign In
- (void)authNoCodeExchange {
    [self verifyConfig];

    NSURL *issuer = [NSURL URLWithString:kIssuer];

    [self logMessage:@"Fetching configuration for issuer: %@", issuer];



    // discovers endpoints
    [OIDAuthorizationService discoverServiceConfigurationForIssuer:issuer
                                                        completion:^(OIDServiceConfiguration *_Nullable configuration, NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                                            if (!configuration) {
                                                                [self logMessage:@"Error retrieving discovery document: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
                                                                return;
                                                            }

                                                            [self logMessage:@"Got configuration: %@", configuration];

                                                            if (!kClientID) {
                                                                [self doClientRegistration:configuration
                                                                                  callback:^(OIDServiceConfiguration *configuration,
                                                                                             OIDRegistrationResponse *registrationResponse) {
                                                                                      [self doAuthWithoutCodeExchange:configuration
                                                                                                             clientID:registrationResponse.clientID
                                                                                                         clientSecret:registrationResponse.clientSecret];
                                                                                  }];
                                                            } else {
                                                                [self doAuthWithoutCodeExchangeCri:configuration clientID:kClientID clientSecret:nil];
                                                            }
                                                        }];
}



/////////////////
- (void)doAuthWithoutCodeExchangeCri:(OIDServiceConfiguration *)configuration
                         clientID:(NSString *)clientID
                     clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret {
    NSURL *redirectURI = [NSURL URLWithString:kRedirectURI];
    OIDTokenRequest *tokenExchangeRequest =
    [_authState.lastAuthorizationResponse tokenExchangeRequest];
    [OIDAuthorizationService performTokenRequest:tokenExchangeRequest
                                        callback:^(OIDTokenResponse *_Nullable tokenResponse,
                                                   NSError *_Nullable error) {

                                            if (!tokenResponse) {
                                                [self logMessage:@"Token exchange error: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
                                            } else {
                                                [self logMessage:@"Received token response with accessToken: %@", tokenResponse.accessToken];
                                            }



                                            [_authState updateWithTokenResponse:tokenResponse error:error];


                                            GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization *gtmAuthorization =
                                            [[GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization alloc] initWithAuthState:authState];

                                            // Sets the authorizer on the GTLRYouTubeService object so API calls will be authenticated.
                                            self.youTubeService.authorizer = gtmAuthorization;

                                            // Serializes authorization to keychain in GTMAppAuth format.
                                            [GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization saveAuthorization:gtmAuthorization
                                                                            toKeychainForName:kGTMAppAuthKeychainItemName];

                                            [self uploadVideoFile];

                                        }];

}
```

i have also something like:

```
NSString * RetrivedToken = @"ya29xxxxxxx3nJxxxxxxx6qqQ-FxxxxxxxdGH";
```

How i can modify those methods to accept my retrivedtoken instead the one they retrive from the standard auth workflow?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but its going to be to big for a comment.

So you want to create an app that will allow others to upload to your youtube channel.  Normally i would say use a service account which would allow you to do this much easier.  However the YouTube api does not support service accounts.

You are going to need to authenticate the app once save your refresh token then embed this refresh token in your app.

Why this is not a good idea with a mobile app.

Refresh tokens can expire so if it does expire or break then your going to have to authenticate the app again and embed the new refresh token into your app and release a new version to your users.

An alternative would be to set up a web service with the refresh token on that and have your app access the web service for upload.  Then if the refresh token breaks you will only have to fix it on your web service.

I have done this before its messy but there is really no other way of doing it.

Comment: "An alternative would be to set up a web service with the refresh token on that and have your app access the web service for upload. Then if the refresh token breaks you will only have to fix it on your web service." This is the way i choose and i have tried to explain in the question. Is the only reasonable way i think... Do you know how i can modify the code to accept the web-service token instead the standard token?

Comment: I kinda disagree that setting up a web service is a messy solution. Quite contrary, I think it's really the only viable solution. Having the tokens and client credentials ([as you need them to get new access tokens with the refresh token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline)) stored within the app means they can be extracted and used in an unintended way.

Comment: @paolo its more messy then using a service account would have been.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from your code

```
if (!tokenResponse) {
[self logMessage:@"Token exchange error: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
} else {
[self logMessage:@"Received token response with accessToken: %@", tokenResponse.accessToken];
 }
```

your are using OIDTokenResponse object tokenResponse in your further code.
First make an object of Class OIDTokenResponse like *oidTokenResponse and assign it your access token from your server like

```
oidTokenResponse.accessToken=YOUR_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER;
```

and then use

```
[_authState updateWithTokenResponse:oidTokenResponse error:error];
```

In other way you can also do that and you won't need to change your code much you can do it with one line of code but i'm not sure you are allow to change to access token here but you can try it.

Leave the other code and just add one more line in your else

```
if (!tokenResponse) {
[self logMessage:@"Token exchange error: %@", [error    localizedDescription]];
} else {
[self logMessage:@"Received token response with accessToken: %@",      tokenResponse.accessToken];
tokenResponse.accessToken=YOUR_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER;
}
```

Comment: oidTokenResponse.accessToken  is readonly , i can't set it in that way

Comment: Ok then make an object of OIDTokenResponse and assign your Server Token to it because from your code i can see that your are using tokenResponse further.

Comment: to init an oidtokenresponse i need a request: OIDTokenResponse *sfd=[[OIDTokenResponse alloc] initWithRequest:<#(nonnull OIDTokenRequest *)#> parameters:<#(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,NSObject<NSCopying> *> *)#>] , and for what i see there's no way to create a request for a fixed token

Comment: There is another way you can do it by saving tokenResponse at the server. TokenResponse also include Token as well